# C++ lambda to std::function error with non const strings

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

The following line gives error in c++ 11:

```
function<bool(string,string)> comp = [] (string& s1, string& s2) {return s1.length() > s2.length(); };
```

but this does not:

```
function<bool(string,string)> comp = [] (const string& s1, const string& s2) {return s1.length() > s2.length(); };
```

The second call has const in parameters. Any explanation?

Comment: Temporary objects or literals can't be bound to references to non-constant objects. [Any good beginners book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) should have told you so.

Comment: rvalues (such as parameters passed by value) cannot bind to non-const lvalue references, but can bind to const lvalue references.

Comment: You know auto works for lambda? `auto comp = ...`

Comment: `bool(string,string)` is rather a signature of `std::function`s id-operator rather than of what is contained. They merely have to be compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first case,

```
function<bool(string,string)> comp = [] (string& s1, string& s2) {return s1.length() > s2.length(); };
```

you are trying to compile something like this:

```
bool comp(string& s1, string& s2){/*...*/}
comp(string(), string());//passing a lvalue reference to a rvalue
```

The error here is you are trying to get a non-const lvalue reference to a rvalue, that's a violation of standard.

Fixing solution 1, using `function<bool(string &, string &)>`(I think you probably trying to using this version):

```
function<bool(string&,string&)> comp = [] (string& s1, string& s2) {return s1.length() > s2.length(); };
```

Fixing solution 2, using rvalue reference:

```
function<bool(string,string)> comp = [] (string&& s1, string&& s2) {return s1.length() > s2.length(); };
```

In your second case,

```
function<bool(string,string)> comp = [] (const string& s1, const string& s2) {return s1.length() > s2.length(); };
```

you are trying to get a const lvalue reference to a rvalue, and this violates nothing of standard.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really have anything to do with lambdas. When you declare a function as taking a *const reference*, you activate [lifetime extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary%20%22lifetime%20extension%22.).

```
void foo(const std::string& ref){ . . . }
void bar(std::string& ref){ . . . }

foo(std::string("hello"));
```

Is allowed - the lifetime of the string containing hello is *extended* throughout the exection of `foo`.

For non-const references, there is no such extension rule, so the compiler will not allow:

```
bar(std::string("farewell"));
```

because if it did, at the point `foo` starts, it would only have a reference to the destructed remnants of what was once the farewell string.

Answer (score 1):

From C++11 Standard § 20.8.11.2:

> ```
> template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
> class function<R(ArgTypes...)> { /* ... */ };
>
> template<class F> function(F f);
> ```
>
> Requires: `f` shall be *Callable* for argument types `ArgTypes`
> and return type `R`.

In your first case, *Callable* means that

```
INVOKE(f, declval<string>(), declval<string>(), bool)
```

is well formed, where `f` is lambda and `declval` represents rvalue objects of type `string`. Since rvalues cannot be bound to *non-const lvalue references*, this condition is not satisfied here.

On the contrary, rvalues can be bound to *const lvalue references*, thus the second case is ok.